# Kill GUI "zombie"

Tags: macos

This is not actually zombie in UNIX terms, but I don't know name of this process.

On my Mavericks 10.9.1 some GUI application has been badly crashed and I can't run it again except I should logout (reboot?) and login again.

`ps gauxwww` shows it as "(AppName)", in `Application Monitor` I see application `AppName` with icon which consumes `0`(zero) of any resources. Parent PID is `1`.

Killing it with `-KILL` or with any other signal doesn't help at all, I can "run" application: icon will jump on Dock, and I can't do anything at all except `Force Quit` with no quitting that "zombie".

What should I do without reboot my mac to rid out that process?

**UPD:** there's no such process in `spindump` or same utilities. What the hell are such processes?

Comment: did you do a virus check

Comment: If you have an app running on your computer, it has to reside somewhere on the disk. I would monitor the Console to see if I can catch it in action.

Comment: I can't reproduce it when I want to. There may be some deadlock or endless waiting for resource cause this problem.

Comment: I reproduce the problem and ask a question before finding your post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/killing-an-application

Comment: @MartinDelille, I had this problem with `Maverics` only. It has been gone with `Yosemite` release.