# Killing an application

Tags: applications, bug, restart

I try to kill a buggy application without success.

I tried the *Force Quit…* feature in the Apple menu but it doesn't work.

In order to find the PID I tried the following command from the *Terminal* but it doesn't match anything:

```
ps aux | grep -i MyApplicationName
```

The only way to effectively kill it is to restart the system. Sometimes I need to force restart because the buggy application is preventing the system to restart.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5 on a Retina 13' MacBook (late 2013)

Comment: Could you tell me which system version do you have?

Comment: @EirNym I just edit my post

Comment: I had this issue on 10.9. After I have had moved to 10.10, issue has gone.

Comment: I'm not confident enough in 10.10 for now: I hear so much bad thing about it like if it was the apple "vista" :-)

Comment: I'm quit sure this is a bug from the OS.

Comment: Many issues which was in 10.9 has gone by themselves. I work in this OS since beta4 and have no headaches with it.

Comment: have you ever tried to kill with `sudo`? And if there is a parent process that always fork the process, you should also kill that.

Answer (score 2):

Find the PID in activity monitor then in a terminal run `sudo kill -9 PID` and *voilà*

Comment: This not working: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121911/kill-gui-zombie?noredirect=1

Comment: How do I find the PID? ps aux doesn't find the application

Comment: Even in the activity monitor?

Comment: Nope: it's like if it was a zombie...

Comment: @EirNym no but it looks like it is the same problem

Comment: @MartinDelille, ok

Comment: Then you have to kill the parent... But how to find out what it is...?

Comment: @Thomas I'm asking the questions here ;-)

Comment: @MartinDelille on a zombie process the PPID is 1 but I doubt you can kill 1...